# http server python receive data POST but only the message

Tags: python, http, server

Hello i want to create a little http python server for receive some informations. I'm trying to send information from unity to my server. I saw it is possible to see the data with :

```
self.rfile.read(content_length)
```

[here was what i received on the server after sent text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrOC2.png)

Can it be possible to have only "test"?

Thank you.

Comment: BaseHTTPServer is very basic and low level. If you don't want to do this manual work yourself, try something like `flask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used socket. because i think

```
self.rfile.read(content_length)
```

is indivisible.